# Angular Library and peer dependencies

Tags: angular, dependencies

I am writing an angular library. It has two independent module within.
I am including two external packages in peer dependencies ,which each of the above said module depends on.
 Issue:
   When library users import only the first module, how can I make library work just by using only the dependant package ,instead of forced to install both of the external libraries?

Detail
   Module A. depends on. external package-a
   Module B depends on external package-b

My Library  NgLibModule imports and exports both the above modules.
When a user installs my above library and imports only Module A, and installs its dependency package-a, application complaining of missing package-b.

Any work around for this?